# google places api callback workaround

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

i am looking for a workaround for getting the google search method to return the results of the callback rather than undefined.

```
$.find_places_nearby = function(latitude, longitude, successCallback) {
  var latlng, service;
  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('map'));
  return service.search({
    location: latlng,
    radius: '50',
  }, function(results, status) {
    return successCallback(results, status);
  });
};
```

for example... i want

```
$.find_places_nearby(2.4, -100.5, function(results, status) {
  return "callback results";
});
```

to return `callback results` instead of `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The callback function is explicitly executed at some undefined later point in time, *asynchronously*. The call to `$.find_places_nearby()` will explicitly not return anything, rather you are passing code that should be executed with the result of that call as callback. It does not make sense to return something from that callback.

Comment: indeed. its hard to see when you are deep in a rabbit hole. thanks for the fresh eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) objects.
The promise pattern lets you do asynchronous stuff but still maintain a more linear flow.